# How do you use apm_get in Gekko?

Tags: python, gekko

When troubleshooting Gekko outputs, how do I access the `infeasibilities.txt` file? I'm using
`m = GEKKO(remote=False)` so I don't know what to use for the `server` and `app` parameters in `apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt')` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are solving with `remote=True` on the public server then you can retrieve the file from the server.

```py
from gekko.apm import get_file
print(m._server)
print(m._model_name)
f = get_file(m._server,m._model_name,'infeasibilities.txt')
f = f.decode().replace('\r','')
with open('infeasibilities.txt', 'w') as fl:
    fl.write(str(f))
```

If you are solving with `remote=False` then there is no need to get the file from the server. It will be available in the run folder `m.path` or viewable with `m.open_folder()`. There are more details on [How to retrieve the 'infeasibilities.txt' from the gekko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671888/how-to-retrieve-the-infeasibilities-txt-from-the-gekko)