# Infeasibilities, Solution Not Found - Gekko Error

Tags: python, optimization, controls, gekko

I'm Arthur. I'm very new to gekko, thus I might be missing something very obvious here.

I have been trying to find the solution to an optimal control problem, namely trajectory optimization of a spacecraft rendezvous problem (Chaser -> Target), under certain final constraints to the relative final distance and velocity and certain distance along their trip. In order to do this, I tried using soft constraints to the final path. As a objective function, I use a norm 1 of the force generated from Thrusters.

The computation keeps going until the maximum no. of iterations (2000) is reached and cancels. Is there maybe a way to discretize the search space of this problem to make it solvable in acceptable time trading off computation time for accuracy?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from gekko import GEKKO

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
print(m.path)
nt = 501
m.time = np.linspace(0,500,nt)

# Variables

# Initial Position and Velocity - Chaser
r1_c = -1182.339411   # [km] 
r2_c = 6816.939420    # [km] 
r3_c = 904.891745     # [km] 
v1_c = 0.1175776      # [km/s] 
v2_c = -0.963776      # [km/s] 
v3_c = 7.494102       # [km/s] 

# Initial Position and Velocity - Target
r1_t = -1182.959348    # [km] 
r2_t = 6817.396210     # [km] 
r3_t = 904.495486      # [km] 
v1_t = 0.1175776       # [km/s] 
v2_t = -0.963776       # [km/s] 
v3_t = 7.494102        # [km/s] 

# initial values
x =  m.Var(value = r1_c)
y =  m.Var(value = r2_c)
z =  m.Var(value = r3_c)
vx =  m.Var(value = v1_c)
vy =  m.Var(value = v2_c)
vz =  m.Var(value = v3_c)


# initial values
x2 =  m.Var(value = r1_t)
y2 =  m.Var(value = r2_t)
z2 =  m.Var(value = r3_t)
vx2 =  m.Var(value = v1_t)
vy2 =  m.Var(value = v2_t)
vz2 =  m.Var(value = v3_t)

# Cost Initial - Integrated thrust (fuel usage)
J =  m.Var(value = 0)

# Manipulated Variable
U = m.MV(value=0, lb=-0.001, ub=0.001)

U.STATUS = 1

# Mask time
p = np.zeros(nt) # mask final time point
p[-1] = 500
final = m.Param(value=p)

# Parameters
RT =  m.Const(6378.139);            # [km] 
mu_t = m.Const(3.9860064*10**(5))   # [km^3/s^2] 


# Equations

# Define intermediate quantities - Chaser
Rc = m.Intermediate((x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5)
v = m.Intermediate((vx**2 + vy**2 + vz**2)**0.5)

ax = m.Intermediate(x * -mu_t / Rc**3 + U *vx / v )
ay = m.Intermediate(y * -mu_t / Rc**3 + U *vy / v )
az = m.Intermediate(z * -mu_t / Rc**3 + U *vz / v )


# Define intermediate quantities - Target
Rt = m.Intermediate((x2**2 + y2**2 + z2**2)**0.5)
v2 = m.Intermediate((vx2**2 + vy2**2 + vz2**2)**0.5)

ax2 = m.Intermediate(x2 * -mu_t / Rt**3 )
ay2 = m.Intermediate(y2 * -mu_t / Rt**3 )
az2 = m.Intermediate(z2 * -mu_t / Rt**3 )


# Governing equations
m.Equations((vx.dt() == ax, vy.dt() == ay, vz.dt() == az))
m.Equations((x.dt() == vx, y.dt() == vy, z.dt() == vz))

m.Equations((vx2.dt() == ax2, vy2.dt() == ay2, vz2.dt() == az2))
m.Equations((x2.dt() ==  vx2, y2.dt() ==  vy2, z2.dt() == vz2))

# Equation relating thrust to fuel usage
m.Equation(J.dt() == m.abs2(U))


# Path Constraints

# specify endpoint conditions

m.fix(x, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=x2)
m.fix(y, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=y2)
m.fix(z, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=z2)
m.fix(vx, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=vx2)
m.fix(vy, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=vy2)
m.fix(vz, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=vz2)

# Constraints 

m.Equations((m.abs2(Rc - RT) > 200, m.abs2(Rc - RT) < 1000, m.abs2(Rc*final - Rt*final) == 0, m.abs2(v*final - v2*final) == 0))


# Objective, minimizing fuel usage
m.Obj(J * final)

# Set solver mode - Optimal Control
m.options.IMODE = 6

# Increase maximum number of allowed iterations
m.options.MAX_ITER = 2000

# Set number of nodes per time segment
m.options.NODES = 3

# Run solver and display progress
m.solve(disp=True)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :    3663.92820000000      sec
 Objective      :    185346862893.104     
 Unsuccessful with error code            0
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
 Creating file: infeasibilities.txt
 Use command apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt') to retrieve file
 @error: Solution Not Found
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It does not find the solution and I do not find the file `infeasibilities.txt`.

Can you help me please?

I would like to find the reason from results (Solution Not Found). However someone can help me with structure of the problem becoming it feasible.

Comment: Here is some help on retrieving the infeasibilities.txt report: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671888/how-to-retrieve-the-infeasibilities-txt-from-the-gekko

Answer (score 0):

One infeasible set of constraints is that `Rc-RT` is set to `>200` and `<1000` everywhere, but it must also equal zero at the final time. The solver can't satisfy these constraints.

```
m.abs2(Rc - RT) > 200
m.abs2(Rc - RT) < 1000
m.abs2(Rc*final - Rt*final) == 0
```

I recommend replacing these constraints with something that is numerically simple with the definition of a new variable with upper and lower bounds and the `**2` to avoid `sqrt()` and `abs()`.

```py
RcRT = m.Var(lb=200,ub=1000)
m.Equation(RcRT**2 == (Rc-RT)**2)
```

The MPCC `m.abs2()` does not work very well for most problems. `m.abs3()` works better, but can take more time to solve as a mixed integer form. Try to avoid the use of `abs()` in the model, when there is an alternative. Equations such as `m.abs2(v*final - v2*final) == 0` will have no solution if the Chaser is not able to match the velocity of the Target. Try a different soft constraint (objective-based) that allows the problem to remain feasible and minimize the difference.

```py
m.Minimize(final*(v-v2)**2)
```

Likewise, these hard constraints may be infeasible:

```py
# hard constraints
m.fix(x, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=x2)
m.fix(y, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=y2)
m.fix(z, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=z2)
m.fix(vx, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=vx2)
m.fix(vy, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=vy2)
m.fix(vz, pos=len(m.time)-1, val=vz2)
```

Try soft constraints:

```py
# soft constraints
m.Minimize(final*(v-v2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(x-x2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(y-y2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(z-z2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(vx-vx2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(vy-vy2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(vz-vz2)**2)
```

Here is the complete problem:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from gekko import GEKKO

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()
print(m.path)
nt = 101
m.time = np.linspace(0,500,nt)

# Variables

# Initial Position and Velocity - Chaser
r1_c = -1182.339411   # [km] 
r2_c = 6816.939420    # [km] 
r3_c = 904.891745     # [km] 
v1_c = 0.1175776      # [km/s] 
v2_c = -0.963776      # [km/s] 
v3_c = 7.494102       # [km/s] 

# Initial Position and Velocity - Target
r1_t = -1182.959348    # [km] 
r2_t = 6817.396210     # [km] 
r3_t = 904.495486      # [km] 
v1_t = 0.1175776       # [km/s] 
v2_t = -0.963776       # [km/s] 
v3_t = 7.494102        # [km/s] 

# initial values
x =  m.Var(value = r1_c)
y =  m.Var(value = r2_c)
z =  m.Var(value = r3_c)
vx =  m.Var(value = v1_c)
vy =  m.Var(value = v2_c)
vz =  m.Var(value = v3_c)


# initial values
x2 =  m.Var(value = r1_t)
y2 =  m.Var(value = r2_t)
z2 =  m.Var(value = r3_t)
vx2 =  m.Var(value = v1_t)
vy2 =  m.Var(value = v2_t)
vz2 =  m.Var(value = v3_t)

# Cost Initial - Integrated thrust (fuel usage)
J =  m.Var(value = 0)

# Manipulated Variable
U = m.MV(value=0, lb=-0.001, ub=0.001)
U.STATUS = 1

# Mask time
p = np.zeros(nt) # mask final time point
p[-1] = 500
final = m.Param(value=p)

# Parameters
RT =  m.Const(6378.139);            # [km] 
mu_t = m.Const(3.9860064*10**(5))   # [km^3/s^2] 

# Equations

# Define intermediate quantities - Chaser
Rc = m.Intermediate((x**2 + y**2 + z**2)**0.5)
v = m.Intermediate((vx**2 + vy**2 + vz**2)**0.5)

ax = m.Intermediate(x * -mu_t / Rc**3 + U *vx / v )
ay = m.Intermediate(y * -mu_t / Rc**3 + U *vy / v )
az = m.Intermediate(z * -mu_t / Rc**3 + U *vz / v )

# Define intermediate quantities - Target
Rt = m.Intermediate((x2**2 + y2**2 + z2**2)**0.5)
v2 = m.Intermediate((vx2**2 + vy2**2 + vz2**2)**0.5)

ax2 = m.Intermediate(x2 * -mu_t / Rt**3 )
ay2 = m.Intermediate(y2 * -mu_t / Rt**3 )
az2 = m.Intermediate(z2 * -mu_t / Rt**3 )


# Governing equations
m.Equations((vx.dt() == ax, vy.dt() == ay, vz.dt() == az))
m.Equations((x.dt() == vx, y.dt() == vy, z.dt() == vz))

m.Equations((vx2.dt() == ax2, vy2.dt() == ay2, vz2.dt() == az2))
m.Equations((x2.dt() ==  vx2, y2.dt() ==  vy2, z2.dt() == vz2))

# Equation relating thrust to fuel usage
#m.Equation(J.dt() == m.abs2(U))
m.Equation(J.dt()**2 == U**2)


# Path Constraints

# specify endpoint conditions
# soft constraints
m.Minimize(final*(v-v2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(x-x2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(y-y2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(z-z2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(vx-vx2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(vy-vy2)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(vz-vz2)**2)    

# Constraints 
# m.abs2(Rc - RT) > 200
# m.abs2(Rc - RT) < 1000
# m.abs2(Rc*final - Rt*final) == 0
RcRT = m.Var(lb=200,ub=1000)
m.Equation(RcRT**2 == (Rc-RT)**2)

# Objective, minimizing fuel usage
m.Minimize(J * final)

# Set solver mode - Optimal Control
m.options.IMODE = 6

# Increase maximum number of allowed iterations
m.options.MAX_ITER = 2000

# Set number of nodes per time segment
m.options.NODES = 3

# Run solver and display progress
m.solve(disp=True)
```

IPOPT finds an optimal solution after 1375 iterations with a reduced the number of time points to 101 for testing. You can try to increase the number of time points and resolve.

```
1375 -1.3996401e+02 2.04e-09 8.64e-07 -10.5 1.61e-06    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
Number of Iterations....: 1375
                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:  -4.4944986703206206e-03   -1.3996401074391898e+02
Dual infeasibility......:   8.6432001202008113e-07    2.6915948656834957e-02
Constraint violation....:   7.7449958484773991e-10    2.0372681319713593e-09
Complementarity.........:   3.3628245954861400e-11    1.0472233998435268e-06
Overall NLP error.......:   8.6432001202008113e-07    2.6915948656834957e-02

Number of objective function evaluations             = 1974
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 1149
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 1982
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 1982
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 1389
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 1389
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 1375
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =     83.311
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =    112.375

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
 The solution was found.
 The final value of the objective function is   -139.964010743919     
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :    199.320599999999      sec
 Objective      :   -139.964010743919     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```