# Why does objective function for some iteration shows as NaN

Tags: python, gekko

I have a Gekko model and is currently experimenting with different objective functions.  Most of the objective functions is built with `.COST` and  `.DCOST` constructs on `CV` and `MV` variables augmented by some additional `Maximize` and `Minimize` statements.  However, what happens is that some permutations of these seem to cause the Objective function value for some iterations to become NaN, as shown in the attached picture.  I not sure if that means that the Obj function when calculated for some values result division by zero, inf or otherwise undefined.  I will appreciate some pointers as to how to overcome this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before convergence, the objective function is a weighted combination of the true objective and equation residuals. At convergence, the objective function is equal to the originally defined objective because the equation residuals are zero. The `NaN` can occur because of a division by zero, a trigonometric function that evaluates to infinity, or because of imaginary numbers such as `sqrt(-value)`. The `NaN` indicates that the solver is diverging. The solver rarely recovers because the `NaN` objective also means that some equation gradients are missing. Here are three suggestions:

**1. Eliminate divide-by-zero variables in all equations.** It is not necessary to eliminate divide-by-zero for constants that are non-zero. Below is an equation where the density `ρ` is a calculated variable.

```py
m.Equation(v.dt() == (m_in - m_out)/ρ)
```

Eliminating divide-by-zero is typically a simple multiplication to both sides of the equation.

```py
m.Equation(ρ*v.dt() == m_in - m_out)
```

**2. Add variable bounds.** Adding variable bounds helps avoid divide-by-zero, but can also help the solver find a solution. Examples are variables bounds of `(0-1)` for mole fractions and `(0-10000)` for temperatures.

```py
ρ = m.Var(1.0,lb=0.01,ub=10)
```

Relax (widen) the variable bounds if the solver reports an infeasible problem.

**3. Identify infeasible constraints and equations.** Set `m.options.max_iter=10` to terminate early and look at the `infeasibilities.txt` file report. Here is help on retrieving that file: [How to retrieve the 'infeasibilities.txt' from the gekko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671888/how-to-retrieve-the-infeasibilities-txt-from-the-gekko)