# GEKKO solution not converging to sufficiently small number

Tags: gekko

The accepted answer on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75297220/why-does-objective-function-for-some-iteration-shows-as-nan) regarding NaN in objective function helped a lot.  I now somehow run into the problem where the convergence value reported does not go below a certain value as [depicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPSnS.png) below:

```
Iter    Objective  Convergence
  20 -1.55305E+04  1.78101E+00
  21 -1.54846E+04  1.78101E+00
  22 -1.55665E+04  1.42371E+00
  23 -1.55675E+04  1.42371E+00
  24 -1.55209E+04  1.78101E+00
  25 -1.54972E+04  2.00348E+00
  26 -1.54750E+04  1.78101E+00
  27 -1.54835E+04  1.78101E+00
  28 -1.55488E+04  1.78101E+00
  29 -1.55047E+04  1.78101E+00
  
Iter    Objective  Convergence
  30 -1.55043E+04  1.78101E+00
  31 -1.55043E+04  1.78101E+00
  32 -1.55054E+04  1.78101E+00
  33 -1.55058E+04  1.78101E+00
  34 -1.55517E+04  1.78101E+00
```

The context of the problem might be appropriate.  I am optimising a complex *make-store-use* system.  The inventory limits of the *store* subsystem are represented as `CV`'s that have obvious integrator models to the inventory balance around the storage system.  At times it might be useful to the evaluate the  decoupling of the *make* and  *use* sub--systems , i.e. prevent limitations on the *use* subsystem to turn down the *make* sub-system.  This can be done by 'dropping' the inventory `CV`'s by setting `cv.STATUS=0`.  When I do that the convergence gets stuck at 1.78 and after maximum iteration an unsuccessful solution is reported.  When the inventory are controlled within bounds, the solution converge within a few iterations with convergence reported as 0.00004.  (`OTOL`=0.1, `RTOL`=0.01).

The inventories is part of the objective function via `cv.COST`=-0.01 to incentivise building inventory when possible.

I am suspecting that because of the integrating model of the inventories and the fact that it is not controlled but still form part of the objective function, non-convergence might be inferred.   If so, how should I treat such problems?

Answer (score 1):

Without specific code for testing, it is difficult to diagnose the problem. Here are a few ideas:

1. If using `m.options.CV_TYPE=1` (`l1-norm` objective), try setting a small `WSPHI` and `WSPLO` value such as `1e-5` instead of turning off the CV with `STATUS=0`. This effectively de-prioritizes the inventory CV, but still tries to minimize `e_hi` and `e_lo` from the [l1-norm objective](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerObjective). With no minimization, `e_hi` and `e_lo` can be any value and make it more difficult to converge.
2. Set a lower bound on the `make` and `use` rates of `0` and a reasonable upper bound. There is often a failure to converge if a quantity, such as inventory, is unbounded towards infinity.
3. Check the scaling on the equations. Unit conversions can help to avoid very large or very small gradient values that are difficult to converge. For example, if there is a population balance for the world:

```py
population = m.Var(7.9e9)
m.Equation(population.dt() == birth_rate - death_rate)
```

because the population is very large, I would divide by a scaling factor such as `1e9` to scale the units to billons of people.

```py
s = 1e9; population = m.Var(7.9)
m.Equation(population.dt() == (birth_rate - death_rate)/s)
```

I'm not sure why scaling would make a difference if the `STATUS` is off or on, but it is something I check when the solver has trouble converging.